# Cannot access to 2 of 3 nodes in elasticsearch cluster (only first) via browser with http://localhost:9200, 9201, 9203. Is this normal and why?

Tags: elasticsearch, browser, nodes, cluster-computing

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.1
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.1
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9201:9201
    networks:
      - elastic

  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.1
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9202:9202
    networks:
      - elastic


  kib01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.9.1
    container_name: kib01
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://es01:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

I am trying to understand how elasticsearch cluster nodes work where end clients can access the cluster through any of the nodes. The nodes' roles are kept default to be master eligible and store data.

Running this elasticsearch cluster from the guide, I am able to access Node es01 through the browser. es02 & es03 however is not accessible. I am getting a "The connection was reset" message on firefox.

Now should node 2 & 3 be accessible through browser or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your docker-compose file, es01, es02 and es03, run into our container with default listing port *9200* (this port could be set in a configuration file).

So it's ok when you check the *localhost:9200* you have the response of es01, but when you check *localhost:9201*, this point on *es02:9201* and on this no process listen this port, into the container, es02 listen *9200*.
Same issue for es03.

To fix it just change the mapping port on your docker-compose file. This must looks like this for es02 for example :

```
ports:
  - 9201:9200
```

Comment: Oh of course..... now the question seems silly. 
Yes, changing the maps to 9201:9200, 9202:9200 works. es02 & es03 are accessible now.

Thank you.